# Update to bootstrap 3 has messed up my circle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have updated to bootstrap 3.  Previously I had a div which was a circle and inside that circle there was an icon which was taken from a glyph-icon. It was a perfect circle, now the circle is more of a round rectangle. If I have no icon in the circle, it will be a circle, but as soon as I put an icon into the circle it turns into a rectangle. This was not happening with the previous version of bootstrap. The jsfiddle has my current code. The fiddle will show a circle because I can't add a glyph-icon (of a check mark) into the fiddle, but if it was there (the class on the list tag, fa-icon-check, is what gets the icon) it would be a round rectangle instead of a circle. How can I get the circle to stay a circle when an icon is inside?

**CSS:**

```
.icons-box {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.icons-box i {
    font-size: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50em;
    -moz-border-radius: 50em;
    border-radius: 50em;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 45px 42px;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="background:#000;">
        <div class="icons-box">
            <!-- fa-icon-check is an icon that comes from glyphicons -->
            <i class="fa-icon-check"></i>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1vox25o7/

Comment: `fa` icon comes from `font-awesome` right? Good if you post old behavior and new behavior separately!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes they do. Sorry I am unsure what you mean by old and new. I have not changed the code at all. I just upgraded bootstrap. In the old way the icon inside the circle would always be inside a circle, now when the icon is inside the circle the circle turns into a vertically stretched circle (rounded rectangle)

Comment: What was the old bootstrap version?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It was a version from 2012, I believe it was v2.2.0.

Comment: The fiddle you have created does not represent the problem you are facing.. You need to create problem in fiddle by adding reference to `bootstrap` libraries.. and `<i class="fa-icon-check"></i>` should have one more class called just `fa` initially.. like `fa fa-icon-check`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have now added the libraries

Comment: @GuruprasadRao to the external sources of the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91048/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-user2924127).

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Boot strap glyph-icons within Circle:-

```
<style>

.btn-round {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.btn-round.btn-lg {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}

.btn-round.btn-sm {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}

.btn-round.btn-xs {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
</style>






    <!-- large buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span></button>

<!-- default size buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></span></button>

<!-- small buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>

<!-- extra small buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
```